# expr does not return the pattern if not at the beginning of the string

Tags: bash

Using this version of bash:

```
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

How can I get `expr` to find my pattern within a string, if the pattern I'm looking for does not begin this string?

Example:

```
expr match "123 abc 456 def ghi789" '\([0-9]*\)' #returns 123 as expected
expr match "z 123 abc 456 def ghi789" '\([0-9]*\)' #returns nothing
```

In the second example, I would expect 123 to be returned.

**Further analysis:**

If I start from the end of the string by adding `.*` in my command, I get a weird result:

```
expr match "123 abc 456 def ghi789" '.*\([0-9]*\)' #returns nothing
expr match "123 abc 456 def ghi789" '.*\([0-9]\)' #returns 9 as expected
expr match "123 abc 456 def ghi789 z" '.*\([0-9]\)' #returns also 9
```

Here, it seems that the pattern can be found at the end of the string (so at the beginning of my search), and also if it's not at the end of the string. But it does not work if I add the `*` at the end of the regular expression.

In the other hand, the same does not apply if I start from the beginning of my string:

```
expr match "z 123 abc 456 def ghi789" '\([0-9]\)' #returns nothing
```

I think I must misunderstand something obvious, but I cannot find what.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: The info from `man expr` hints at an "anchored" match ... cf. the suggested answer from @Kleidersack

Comment: what is the specific pattern you want to match? Your search patterns are looking for numbers in general and you have `123`, `456`, `ghi789` in your search string which all are numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I don't know what is an "anchored match". I will look for it. What I'm trying to find is the first digits in a row. Kleidersack answer works well!

Comment: Unless you need POSIX compatibility, don't use `expr`: use `[[ "x 123 abc 456 def ghi789 =~ ([0-9]*) ]]`. If that succeeds, the captured text is in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would
`expr match "123 abc 456 def ghi789 z" '[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)`
do it? (Just added `[0-9]*` instead of `.*` at the beginning)

Like mentioned in the comments - the expression

```
expr match "123 abc 456 def ghi789 z" '^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)
```

would fit better, because the part `^[^0-9]` can be read as "skip all characters which are not digits (`[^0-9]`) form begin (the `^`as first character)"

Comment: Maybe add info from the man page, that `expr` matches "anchored" to explain why adding the 0 or many non digit expression helps?

Comment: Thank you for this proposition, it works fine! Now I will try to find out why :p I think this "anchored"-thing is the key. EDIT: ok I have it. So by default, `expr` is adding a ^ at the beginning of my pattern as if it was anchored.